# How to get only even numbers in a list comprehension of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to take a starting and a length and return a list of lists that gradually increases an even starting integer by 2

For example:

```
evenIncrease 6 3
```

Should return:
`[[6],[6,8],[6,8,10]]`

I am new to Haskell and so far my attempt looks like this:

```
evenIncrease n l = [[n..i] | i <- [n..n+(l*2)-2], even i]
```

but when I attempt my example of `evenIncrease 6 3`, I get:

`[[6],[6,7,8],[6,7,8,9,10]]`

which is almost what I'm looking for but I don't understand why there are still odd numbers in the inner lists when I am using the guard "even i"

any ideas?

Comment: What would be the result of `evenIncrease 7 3`? `[[7], [7,9], [7,9,11]]`?

Answer (score 6):

You're correctly generating only even *endpoints*, but `[n..i]` still increments by 1, so even though both endpoints are even, you still get e.g `[6..8] = [6,7,8]`. Try `[n,n+2..i]`.

Comment: You are a life saver! :)